# How to get system date on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate

```
NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
```

I get this date one hour earlier. Probably it's because it use UTC.
 
How can I get system current date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[NSDate date]` returns the current date. However, an `NSDate` does not have a timezone of its own, it's just an absolute point in time. The timezone only comes into play when you present the date as a string or convert it into date components (like day, month, hour, etc.).

Use `NSDateFormatter` to get a string representation of the date in the current time zone or use `setTimeZone:` on the date formatter to specify a different one. If you simply use `NSLog`, the date will be presented in the UTC timezone (by implicitly calling `description` on the date object).

Use the `NSCalendar` method [`components:fromDate:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/components%3afromDate%3a) to extract individual components (with a given timezone) from your date for typical comparisons, like "do these two dates fall on the same day in this timezone?".

Comment: But I don't need string I need date (same as on iPhone) because I need to compare date. On iPhone I bar time is 10:30 but when I call [NSdate date] I get 09:30.

Comment: An `NSDate` is a "point in time", not a calendar date, as you might think of it. To get things like day, month, hour etc. for a given time zone, use the `NSCalendar` method [`components:fromDate:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/components:fromDate:). For more information, I recommend reading [this article](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/11/working-with-date-and-time-in-cocoa-part-1/) on working with dates in Cocoa.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your system GMT time and date may be this will help you.